# PostgreSQL - attach to point table the maxium distance value to edge of containing polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, distance

[image]

I'm trying to find the furthest distance from a point to the edge of the polygon it sits in. The polygons in this case have been converted to vertex points.

I have two POINT tables in Postgres (and a POLYGON table with 3 shapes).

One POINT table (vertextable) contains vertex points of the 3 polygons (about 18 points in total). I created this vertex point table using ST_DumpPoints.

The other POINT table (insidepointtable) contains 3 points, each one lies somewhere within each of the original polygons. Each point shares a unique ID number with the polygon vertex points they fall inside (see pic).

I want to create a new table containing the 3 points from insidepointtable and the maximum distance value of the point from vertextable.

I'm having trouble returning just the 3 distinct rows. When I use:

```
CREATE TABLE public.vertexmaxdistances AS
SELECT a.id, ST_MaxDistance(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM public.insidepointtable a, public.vertextable b
WHERE a.id = b.id
ORDER BY id DESC, st_maxdistance DESC;
```

I get every distance to every point returned. How can I get:

```
id   |  st_maxdistance
______________________
1    |             5.5
2    |             4.2
3    |             4.9
```

(for example)

Furthermore, I'd actually like to do this distance attachment for millions of sites. So ideally the solution needs to be scaleable with decent performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to `group by` ID. Then you need to compute the distance and keep the biggest one.

Note that `st_maxDistance` is usefull to know the distance between a point and the furthest part of a polygon

```
CREATE TABLE public.vertexmaxdistances AS
SELECT a.id, max(ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom)) as dist
FROM public.insidepointtable a, public.vertextable b
WHERE a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

For efficiency, you may have to use a lateral join

```
CREATE TABLE public.vertexmaxdistances AS
select a.id, far_pt.dist
from public.insidepointtable a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT
     st_distance(a.geom,b.geom) as dist
     FROM public.vertextable b
     WHERE a.id = b.id
     ORDER BY a.geom <-> b.geom DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS far_pt
ORDER BY a.id DESC;
```

Comment: "Note that st_maxDistance is usefull to know the distance between a point and the furthest part of a polygon", exactly what I'm trying to do. I thought converting the polygon to points would speed up the process. Or am I wrong? Should I skip that step.

Comment: Thanks, your first query returns as expected. Each of the points has the max distance attached.
The second query however returns 0 rows!

Comment: the 2nd query is correct (I just validated it)

Comment: ok I'll have another look. However, your first solution I've accepted as the answer to the OP. As it directly answers the proposed question. However I'll be using Thingumabob's answer as I don't need to create a vertex point table beforehand, instead it directly queries the polygon itself.

Answer (score 3):

To fill in with the mentioned `ST_MaxDistance`, assuming your `<polygontable>` has an `<id>` that matches `insidepointtable.id`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.vertexmaxdistance AS
  SELECT a.id,
         ST_MaxDistance(a.geom, b.geom) AS dist
  FROM   public.insidepointtable AS a
  JOIN   <schema>.<polygontable> AS b
    ON   a.id = b.<id>
;
```

Less complex, no need to extract vertices, but with the caveat that `ST_MaxDistance` is bound to the `GEOMETRY` type, and thus **returns distance in CRS units** (i.e. *degrees* for e.g. EPSG:4326, which are meaningless as a measure).

Comment: my CRS is 27700 (British National Grid) in metres.

Comment: @TheoF well then, nothing to worry about ;-)

Comment: The polygon table does have a matching id yes. I see you use a JOIN poly ON pointid = polyid, whereas I use a WHERE pointid = polyid
    .Is there a performance benefit to using JOIN ON?

Comment: @TheoF in this particular case, no; both your implicit cross join (`FROM <table1>, <table2>`) plus `WHERE` and my `(INNER) JOIN ON` will result in the exact same query plan. the `JOIN` syntax can have significant differences, though, and the table listing like you did can have significant drawbacks! I'd recommend to use the `JOIN` syntax, even if only for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Testing on 1000 polygons with a point inside each (using LIMIT 1000), ThingumaBob's answer takes 22 seconds:

```
CREATE TABLE public.vertexmaxdistance AS
  SELECT a.id, a.geom, ST_MaxDistance(a.geom, b.geom) AS maxdist
  FROM   public.insidepointtable AS a
  JOIN   public.polygon AS b
   ON   a.id = b.id
LIMIT 1000
```

Again testing on 1000 polygons (using LIMIT 1000), my revised solution takes 22 seconds:

```
CREATE TABLE public.vertexmaxdistance AS
SELECT a.id, a.geom, ST_MaxDistance(a.geom, b.geom) AS maxdist
FROM public.insidepointtable a, public.polygon b
WHERE a.id = b.id
LIMIT 1000
```

So there is as suggested, no performance distance using JOIN ON id = id vs. WHERE id = id

(Interestingly, changing the LIMIT to 100 or even 10 produces the same query time...!)

This is not techincally the correct answer to my original question as I specifically asked about distances between **point** and polygon vertex **points**. Not **point** and the **polygon** itself.

Comment: Can this be done in native QGIS Expressions or PyQGIS or Geopandas ?

Comment: @BAlexander I'm not sure as I haven't tried. I'm sure a 'MaxDistance' function exists somewhere in your examples.